# Remove duplicates in one column based on values in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a large data set with 120K rows. In this data set, I have two columns (Column 1 and Column 2), where Column 2 is dependent on Column 1. This data set comes from an ERP db and for some reason, I have duplicates of the same value in column 2. To remove these duplicates, I cannot use the remove duplicates function as the duplicate values in column 2 are linked to more than one unique value in column 1.

for example, if value "A" in Column 1 has a corresponding value "111" in column 2 and for value "B" in Column 1 having a value "111" in Column 2, I don't want excel to assume that it is a duplicate because it is not. It just means, in my case that "111" is used in both "A" and B". But if "111" repeats itself for value "A" or "B" more than once, then I want to delete those duplicates. I hope this makes sense. This is my first post in this forum and I am not sure how to upload a sample file (hence I've created a table  below to show how the data looks like). any help is appreciated.

[Sample data in a snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82dDn.png)

Thanks in Advance

VJ

Comment: You can still use Remove Duplicates, just make sure both columns are being used.

Comment: It actually did work. Thanks Scott. Really appreciate the advise :)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Scott the [remove duplicates](https://www.microassist.com/software-tips/excel-2010-tip-removing-duplicate-data/) functionality should work for you. If your case is different then you may have to state your problem clearly.

Comment: It did work. Thanks to you as well dsaswal

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, select the **Range**- go to **Data**- **Remove Duplicates**- select **Column B** and **Column C**:
[image]